# How to repeat two tables in a row in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a photo collections in vue application. What I want is to have two tables in a row while iterating all of the photo collection something like:

```
<row>
<col>table1 html</col><col>table2 html</col>
<col>table3 html</col><col>table4 html</col>
</row>
<row>
<col>table5 html</col>
</row>
```

If I had 5 photos in the collection the above will be output. It should work for any number of photos but always lining up two photos in a row or single table in the last row if odd number of photos like above example.

Comment: Is this a vue or an html question? Looks like an HTML or CSS question in which case your title is wrong.

Comment: It looks like a "do my work for me" question too. @OP, If you have _zero_ idea on how to do something like this, maybe start with something simpler, like one row per table, then build on top of that to get the result you want. Make sure you add your current attempt to the question so we can work with what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access each row by index:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr v-for="row in Math.ceil(photos.length / 2)">
    <td>
      {{ photos[(row-1)*2] }}
    </td>
    <td v-if="photos[row*2]">
      {{ photos[row*2] }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or use some array calculations directly in the template:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr v-for="row in Math.ceil(photos.length / 2)">
        <td v-for="photo in photos.slice((row - 1)*2, row*2)">
            {{ photo }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or create a computed property for simplicity:

```
<table border=1>
    <tr v-for="photoRow in photoRows">
        <td v-for="photo in photoRow">
            {{ photo }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    photos: [
      'photo 1',
      'photo 2',
      'photo 3',
      'photo 4',
      'photo 5'
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    photoRows: function() {
      return this.photos.reduce((photoRows, curr) => {
        var perRow = 2;
        var prev = photoRows.pop();
        return photoRows.concat(prev.length >= perRow ? [prev, [curr]] : [prev.concat([curr])]);
      }, [[]]);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-for="row in Math.ceil(photos.length / 2)">
      <td>
        {{ photos[(row-1)*2] }}
      </td>
      <td v-if="photos[row*2]">
        {{ photos[row*2] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-for="row in Math.ceil(photos.length / 2)">
      <td v-for="photo in photos.slice((row - 1)*2, row*2)">
        {{photo}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-for="photoRow in photoRows">
      <td v-for="photo in photoRow">
        {{photo}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: great solution although I still to have bend my mind to understand the computed version of the solution!

Comment: Haha, yeah, yeah. Any function that converts `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` into `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5]]` and on will do. Although it does the job, I would hardly use that function code in real life, it’s too unreadable to my taste. I only wrote it like that to prevent SO’s code police to come and say “hey, you shouldn’t use a `for`, there’s this one-liner using `.reduce()`” and start a parallel conversation about it. Also because it is fun (takes a bit of time, but it’s fun) :P